# GLMM - Predição com ID

Tags: r, glmer, lme4

Amigos,

Eu tenho empresas diferentes com características diferentes e cada empresa tem os mesmos cargos
Eu selecionei os dados de vários integrantes de cada cargo de cada empresa e anotei variáveis comportamentais, variando de 0 a 10, para facilitar chamo  x1, x2, x3, essas variáveis foram coletadas mais de uma vez para cada pessoa (ID).

O objetivo é prever a probabilidade de ocorrência de um fato, e cada pessoa também observou-se esse fato ocorreu ou não. (0 ou 1)

Estou enviando um código R  que simula a situação e na hora de prever a probabilidade de ocorrencia do fato  tentei não informar  o ID pois o objetivo é poder prever para qualquer individuo e não para um especifico,

Só que ao final do codigo exibe o seguinte erro no final

```
 "Error in eval (predvars, date, env): object ID not found"
```

(O codigo em R é somente para facilitar a ajuda dos senhores no entendimento do erro, não sendo rigorosamente fiel a situação estudada)

Eu agradeço ajuda dos senhores

```
 library(plyr)
 library(dplyr)
 library(lme4)
 n = 300
 xx<-c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5")
 xxx<-c("e1", "e2", "e3")
 p=0.3
 Empresa = factor(sample(xxx, n, replace=TRUE), levels=xxx, ordered=FALSE)
 Cargo = factor(sample(xx, n, replace=TRUE), levels=xx, ordered=FALSE)

df1 <- data_frame(
   ID = as.integer(runif(n, min = 1, max = n/7)),
   xx1 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
   xx2 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
   xx3 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
   Empresa = Empresa,
   Cargo = Cargo,
   Fato = as.factor(rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = p))
)
 df1 = df1[order(df1$ID, decreasing=FALSE),]
 library(lme4)
 mm2 <- glmer(Fato ~ xx1 + xx2 + xx3 + Cargo +  (1 | ID) + (1 | Empresa / 
 Cargo), data = df1, 
         family = "binomial",control = glmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE))

 n11 <-  data.frame(Empresa=factor("e1", levels = 
 levels(df1$Empresa),ordered=FALSE),
               Cargo=factor("r1", levels = levels(df1$Cargo),ordered=FALSE),
               xx1=8.58, xx2=8.75, xx3=7.92)
predict(mm2, n11, type="response",re.form= ~(1 | Empresa / Cargo))
##
```

Answer (score 1):

Para você fazer as previsões sem utilizar o efeito aleatório, isto é, sem particularizar para o seu "ID", faça:

```
predict(mm2, n11, type="response", re.form = NA)
```

ou

```
predict(mm2, n11, type="response", re.form = 0)
```

O Erro `"Error in eval (predvars, date, env): object ID not found"` acontecia pois provavelmente você estava usando `re.form = ~ (1|ID)` e não havia informado `ID` no seu `n11`.

Mais informações: `?predict.merMod`